# How to get the Glue code/Step definition file generated automatically in cucumber?

Tags: java, eclipse, automation, cucumber

I am completely new to this automation. I know there's something like "Right Click on feature file and skeleton of the step definition file for the feature file would be generated automatically in the console". I am trying to achieve that.

My project is a maven project and its POM entries are :

```
cucumber-junit - 1.2.4
cucumber-core - 1.2.4
cucumber-java - 1.2.4
cucumber-jvm-deps - 1.0.3
cucumber-html-0.2.3
gherkin - 2.12.2
junit - 4.11
selenium-java - 2.53.1
selenium-server - 2.41.0
```

And I have installed Cucumber 0.0.15N plugin in my eclipse - Neon.

Besides I installed all the above, I dont even get the Cucumber editor for feature file(Still opening in a notepad) and I dont see "Cucumber Feature" after I click "Run as".

Answer (score 1):

Build your project from a command line, you will get snippet suggestions when Cucumber can't find any matching steps. Use these suggestions as a basis for implementing your steps in code.

Comment: Adding to Thomas' answer: You can do this by copying the snippets into a Java class file and implementing them. If you are using IntelliJ, you can also generate them by putting your cursor on the undefined step in your feature file (highlighted in yellow), clicking Alt + Enter and selecting the option to add/generate step(s). Personally I prefer to generate / implement one step at a time, so I have an overview of how far along I am with implementing my steps, instead of generating all steps in one go.